# Return Powershell Array in a Job

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm new to the powershell and I'm trying to get the script below to return data into an array that I can pipe out to Out-Gridview. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$scriptblock = {

  Param($comp)
  IF (Test-Connection $comp -Quiet){
    $user = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp | Select-Object username ).Username

    Get-Service -ComputerName $comp -Name "remoteregistry" | start-service -ErrorAction Ignore

    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $comp)
    $vRegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19C7ABD4-4445-48B0-9D02-5A706D080688}")
    $Version = $vRegKey.GetValue("DisplayName")

        Get-Service -ComputerName $comp -Name remoteregistry | stop-service -ErrorAction Ignore

  } ELSE { Write-Host "***$comp ERROR -Not responding***" }
  $result = @($comp,$version,$user) 
}

$comps = get-content -path 'C:\temp\hostnames.txt'
$comps | ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $_ | Out-Null}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

$result | Out-GridView
```

Comment: When you say "isn't working" - please be clear in terms of what you are seeing vs. what you are expecting/want to see instead. We could probably draw some conclusions but there's a million ways to slice this.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. Im getting data from the $comp, $version and $user variables but cant figure out how to add these to an array which I will pipe to an out-gridview.

Comment: What you're looking for is pscustomobject. I'll try and write something up in a minute

Comment: Question, are you using jobs to multithread?

Comment: The way this code is written, it's entirely synchronous - there's no need to even have jobs here in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In order for your variable to make sense to powershell**, you need to replace

```
$result = @($comp,$version,$user)
```

with

```
New-Object psobject -Property @{'ComputerName'=$comp;
          'Version'=$version;
          'User'=$user}
```

The reason is, you're not defining what properties each variable are, just that it is the variable so the output you would get would look weird for sure. DO NOT decalare $result, as it is a variable inside a job, and those are separate instances of powershell. This way is easier.

**In order to finish the output to gridview** you need to pipe `receive-job` to `out-gridview`

```
$comps | ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $_ | Out-Null}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-GridView
```

*Here's how I would actually write your script.... **WITH** declaring `$result`*

```
$scriptblock = {

  Param($comp)
  IF (Test-Connection $comp -Quiet){
    $user = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp | Select-Object username ).Username

    Get-Service -ComputerName $comp -Name "remoteregistry" | start-service -ErrorAction Ignore

    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $comp)
    $vRegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{19C7ABD4-4445-48B0-9D02-5A706D080688}")
    $Version = $vRegKey.GetValue("DisplayName")

        Get-Service -ComputerName $comp -Name remoteregistry | stop-service -ErrorAction Ignore

  } ELSE { Write-Host "***$comp ERROR -Not responding***" }
  $script:result += New-Object psobject -Property @{'ComputerName'=$comp;
          'Version'=$version;
          'User'=$user} 
}
$result = $null
$comps = get-content -path 'C:\temp\hostnames.txt'
$comps | ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $_ | Out-Null}
Get-Job | Wait-Job 

$result | Out-GridView
```

Comment: This is still going to fail as the `$result` object is never returned out of the scope of the scriptblock. Remove the `$result = ` in the scriptblock and just let PS write the object to the pipeline. Then pipe receive-job straight to out-gridview
`Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-GridView`
 or capture the output into a variable and send that to out-gridview.
`$finalresults = Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job; $finalresults | Out-GridView`

Comment: this was covered by `$finalresult` and I've suggested an edit to remove the confusion created by making these separate suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i get chatty. MY edit was not to "get the job" but to configure the variable to be as needed.

Comment: Realized that $result shouldn't be added to, as he is getting the output of the job, and $result wasn't being output in the job

Comment: Hi Robert and Adam, Thanks you very much for your help. I used the first part of Roberts solution which seems to work properly for me. The next thing I need to work on is multithreading my scripts to return the data much more quickly.

Comment: Running the Job is definitely "multithreading", not sure you can do much better. Unless you create a script to multithread without jobs, saving resources and job starting times.